# why does jQuery skip the code if '&' is in the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailto, reserved-words

I am trying to create a mailto button, where it creates the title and body of an email.

My code does its job correctly but I realised if the letter '&' is in the text, then the rest of the code is skipped. so the string is visible until '&', and anything after that will not be in the email body.

Have a look a the example: [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/danials/yfnexfgq/)

```js
var title = "my track title";
var artist= "ArtistA & Artist B";
var trackURL= " http://localhost/music";


var subjectText = title + " by " + artist;
var bodyText = "Check out the track " + title + " by " + artist + " on " + trackURL;

var url = 'mailto:' + '' + '?subject=' + subjectText + '&body=' + bodyText;
$(".email").on("click tap", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location = url;
});
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="email">Send Email</button>
```

In the console it is shown correctly but if you pres the button and open the it in an email application you see that the text is like: `Check out the track my track title by ArtistA` and the rest is missing.

If I change '&' to 'and' it works correctly and shows: `Check out the track my track title by ArtistA and Artist B on  http:/localhost/music`

Any idea how to fix it? i tried `.toString()` but did not work.

Comment: You need to urlencode your strings.

Comment: *"why does jQuery skip"* - jQuery doesn't skip anything. The part of your code that creates and uses the `url` variable is plain JS, but JS isn't skipping either given this is a URL encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `&` is the separator character of the url parameters.

You need to encode you values (*[`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for the texts and [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) for the url*) before adding them to the url string.

```
 var title ="my track title";
        var artist= "ArtistA & Artist B";
        var trackURL= " http://localhost/music";


        var subjectText = encodeURIComponent(title + " by " + artist);
        var bodyText = encodeURIComponent("Check out the track " + title + " by " + artist + " on ") + encodeURI(trackURL);

        var url = 'mailto:' + '' + '?subject=' + subjectText + '&body=' + bodyText;
        $(".email").on("click tap", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.location = url;
        });
        console.log(url);
```